# How to do Nearest Neighbour Analysis using GeoPandas/Geo-Python/GIS?

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geospatial, geopandas

I was following this tutorial nearest neighbor analysis:
https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2017/lessons/L3/nearest-neighbour.html

I get this error:

```
('id', 'occurred at index 0')
```

after i run this:

```
def nearest (row, geom_union, df1, df2, geom1_col='geometry', geom2_col='geometry', src_column=None):
    # Find the nearest point and return the corresponding value from specified column.
    # Find the geometry that is closest
    nearest= df2[geom2_col] == nearest_points(row[geom1_col], geom_union)[1]
    #Get the corresponding value from df2 (matching is based on the geometry)
    value = df2[nearest][src_column].get_values()[0]
    return value

df1['nearest_id'] = df1.apply(nearest, geom_union=unary_union, df1=df1, df2=df2, geom1_col='centroid', src_column='id', axis=1)
```

I am using my own data for this. It is similar to the one given in example. But i have the addresses, geometry, latitude and longitude in a shp file. So i am not using a .kml file. I can`t figure out this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the code literally,

> df1['nearest_id'] = df1.apply(nearest, geom_union=unary_union, 
>                                     df1=df1, df2=df2, geom1_col='centroid', 
>                                     **src_column='id'**, axis=1)

Then the problem is likely `src_column` - the function returns the value of the column `src_column` argument, which is given value `id` by the sample code. If you get problem with column `id`, most likely you don't have a column with such name and should provide the name of existing column in your dataset.

Comment: I wasn't following the code literally. I had different function/variable/column names. For posting here, i was just using the example names as reference. But yeah you were right, i had put the wrong spelling for my src_column. It was a really simple issue, idk how i missed it. Thanks for the help.